# Foundation weirdness seen on outside of a house we love. Should we walk away?

Tags: foundation

My husband and I are househunting and recently fell in love with this house. But while walking around the outside of the house, we discovered something unusual with the foundation. Naturally, we were a little alarmed, but the seller didn’t disclose any issues with the foundation. I’ll include some pictures of what it looks like. We are really trying to avoid major structural issues and potential mold. Any input would be helpful.[hole in foundation with brick inside](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwDXA.jpg)

foundation with missing bricks and black substance applied
[image: foundation with missing bricks and black substance applied]

foundation with pile of bricks
[image: foundation with pile of bricks]

hole in foundation with brick inside
[image: hole with brick inside]

Comment: That hole shown in the picture link should be repaired.  It should be a simple repair with just filling it with cement, just to keep bugs/small animals out, along with keeping water out.  If that is the only problem I would not worry too much, but do have a look inside looking for stains(water leak problems).  The bricks on the wall do not seem to have any cracks in them showing movement of the foundation(closer look also).

Comment: Get it inspected by a structural engineer / building surveyor.

Comment: Agree with Solar Mike: get a professional's opinion.  Hire an inspector or structural engineer to see it in person.  Get a clear explanation of what's happening, don't accept a "that's fine."  What's with the bricked over opening in lower left of the 1st picture?

Comment: We can't assess a foundation through this tiny internet tube, and we can't tell you how to respond to such an assessment anyway. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

> foundation with missing bricks and black substance applied

I don't know why the bricks are stacked to the side. Seems like they used to form some sort of facade to make the foundation prettier? It's anyone's guess.

The black substance is either black tar or a rubberized membrane which is supposed to act as a vapor barrier. This stuff is quite common.

> hole in foundation with brick inside

The hole seems oddly intentional. It doesn't appear to be a structural defect. Hopefully no rodents/bugs have made it their home. After move-in you should inspect it and fill it with concrete or mortar. If you're doing a home inspection then make sure to point out that concern.

---

You should consider using Google Images to look up "[foundation problems](https://www.google.com/search?q=foundation%20problems&tbm=isch)" and you will quickly see that you have none of those problems.

[image]